# Unity 2019.3.1 SDK/JDK/NDK/GRADLE which version should I download?

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, gradle, sdk, android-ndk

Hello I want to build my game to android but I need to know which version should I use of sdk,jdk,ndk and gradle? If you guys know, can give me the download links?

Comment: Would these installers work for you? https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2019.3.1

Answer (score 1):

The manual for 2019.3 https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html recommends using the unity installer to add these components for you.

Otherwise it states a minimum supported version is Android 4.4, "KitKat", API level 19. you could follow these older steps https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/Manual/android-sdksetup.html to manually download the needed components. I would personally use the latest available, unless I am targeting a device which requires a specific version